Trying to pase a string in javascript
I have this string, which is basically is an array of json objects, but it is a string
"[{'RK': 1, 'RN': 'CB6402AT', 'Marka': 'Zeleno', 'Model': 'Suzuki', 'G_PR': 1997, 'KM': 10000, 'Kupe': 'A', 'Rama': 'B', 'Dvigatel': 'C', 'Descr': datetime.date(2024, 2, 14), 'Problem': 'нагънат преден ляв калник', 'R_DATA': 'не пали', 'ime': 'Пешо', 'telefon': '0881111111'}, {'RK': 2, 'RN': 'CB8888VW', 'Marka': 'Volkswagen', 'Model': 'Passat', 'G_PR': 2001, 'KM': 500000, 'Kupe': 'D', 'Rama': 'E', 'Dvigatel': 'F', 'Descr': datetime.date(2023, 6, 8), 'Problem': 'счупен преден капак', 'R_DATA': 'не пали', 'ime': 'Гошо', 'telefon': '0882222222'}, {'RK': 3, 'RN': 'яяяяя', 'Marka': 'уу', 'Model': 'яя', 'G_PR': 111, 'KM': 1110, 'Kupe': '111', 'Rama': '11', 'Dvigatel': '1111', 'Descr': datetime.date(2025, 5, 2), 'Problem': '1111', 'R_DATA': '1111', 'ime': 'Пешо', 'telefon': '0881111111'}]"

I couldn't use JSON.parse with it, because it usually gives me this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

I tried many ways of manipulating the string itself. Unfortunately none of them worked.

That looks nothing like JSON. Where did you get this string from? Can you show us the code that generated it? Maybe even modify it?

Online parsers like https://jsonlint.com/ are a quick way to find errors in your JSON

A few things are off with the original string:
Using double quotes instead of single quotes.
This is not valid JSON because you've used single quotes instead of double quotes. If you replace all single quotes with double quotes you get:
[{"RK": 1, "RN": "CB6402AT", "Marka": "Zeleno", "Model": "Suzuki", "G_PR": 1997, "KM": 10000, "Kupe": "A", "Rama": "B", "Dvigatel": "C", "Descr": datetime.date(2024, 2, 14), "Problem": "нагънат преден ляв калник", "R_DATA": "не пали", "ime": "Пешо", "telefon": "0881111111"}, {"RK": 2, "RN": "CB8888VW", "Marka": "Volkswagen", "Model": "Passat", "G_PR": 2001, "KM": 500000, "Kupe": "D", "Rama": "E", "Dvigatel": "F", "Descr": datetime.date(2023, 6, 8), "Problem": "счупен преден капак", "R_DATA": "не пали", "ime": "Гошо", "telefon": "0882222222"}, {"RK": 3, "RN": "яяяяя", "Marka": "уу", "Model": "яя", "G_PR": 111, "KM": 1110, "Kupe": "111", "Rama": "11", "Dvigatel": "1111", "Descr": datetime.date(2025, 5, 2), "Problem": "1111", "R_DATA": "1111", "ime": "Пешо", "telefon": "0881111111"}]

However, this still is not valid JSON.
Using unescaped datetime.date(...) function calls in the JSON string
I'm guessing this was exported from some python code somewhere given datetime.date() is a common python function for creating date values. JSON.parse() does not know how to interpret this as it is not valid JSON which is causing the parser to throw an error.
To fix this, find all the instances of "Descr": datetime.date(...) and replace them with actual date strings (i.e. "2024-06-17")
[{"RK": 1, "RN": "CB6402AT", "Marka": "Zeleno", "Model": "Suzuki", "G_PR": 1997, "KM": 10000, "Kupe": "A", "Rama": "B", "Dvigatel": "C", "Descr": "2024-04-14", "Problem": "нагънат преден ляв калник", "R_DATA": "не пали", "ime": "Пешо", "telefon": "0881111111"}, {"RK": 2, "RN": "CB8888VW", "Marka": "Volkswagen", "Model": "Passat", "G_PR": 2001, "KM": 500000, "Kupe": "D", "Rama": "E", "Dvigatel": "F", "Descr": "2023-06-08", "Problem": "счупен преден капак", "R_DATA": "не пали", "ime": "Гошо", "telefon": "0882222222"}, {"RK": 3, "RN": "яяяяя", "Marka": "уу", "Model": "яя", "G_PR": 111, "KM": 1110, "Kupe": "111", "Rama": "11", "Dvigatel": "1111", "Descr": "2023-06-08", "Problem": "1111", "R_DATA": "1111", "ime": "Пешо", "telefon": "0881111111"}]

Which is finally valid JSON!
PS: try to use an online JSON parser to figure out why something isn't JSON in the future. Usually they give pretty helpful tips.
